# Getting variable data from string in c#

Tags: c#

I have got data downloaded from url it is as follows.

```
//[
  {
    "id": "2932675",
    "t": "GNK",
    "e": "LON",
    "l": "915.00",
    "l_fix": "915.00",
    "l_cur": "GBX915.00",
    "s": "0",
    "ltt": "5:08PM GMT",
    "lt": "Dec 11,
    "5": 08PM
    "GMT",
    "
    "lt_dts": "2015-12-11T17:08:26Z",
    "c": "-7.50",
    "c_fix": "-7.50",
    "cp": "-0.81",
    "cp_fix": "-0.81",
    "ccol": "chr",
    "pcls_fix": "922.5"
  }
]
```

and want following variable t : GNK and l:915 from above string and done following

```
void method1()
   {
      string scrip = textBox1.Text;
      string s;
      WebClient wc = new WebClient();
      string url = ("http://finance.google.com/finance/infoclient=ig&q=NSE:" + scrip);
      s = wc.DownloadString(url);
      textBox2.Text = s.Substring(58, 6);
      textBox3.Text = s;

     }

        public class LatestPrice
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string l { get; set; }
        public string l_fix { get; set; }
        public string l_cur { get; set; }
        public string s { get; set; }
        public string lt { get; set; }
        public string lt_dts { get; set; }
        public string c { get; set; }
        public string c_fix { get; set; }
        public string cp { get; set; }
        public string cp_fix { get; set; }
        public string ccol { get; set; }
        public string pcls_fix { get; set; }
    }
    public string[][] convert_string()
    {
        string[][] stockprice = null;
        string stockprice1 = null;
        string getdownloadstr = getstring();

        stockprice1 = getdownloadstr.Replace("//", "").Trim();
        var v = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LatestPrice>>(stockprice1);
        }
```

i have made changes to program -- but how to access the t : gnk value or l = 915 value

Comment: You need a JSON decoder - [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) is very good.

Comment: Why do you allow the user to change your 'script'?

Comment: so that user can view different quotes other wise i have to write no of code for no of different quotes by measuring the string length

Comment: can please give example of json decoding

Comment: @supapati - Please see the answer for how to deserialize JSON.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert to `JArray` to `JObject` and can get the value directly through `JOject parameter` key.

```
string jsonStr = "[{ \"id\":\"2932675\", \"t\" : \"GNK\" , \"e\" : \"LON\" , \"l\" : \"915.00\" , \"l_fix\" : \"915.00\" , \"l_cur\" : \"GBX915.00\" , \"s\": \"0\" , \"ltt\":\"5:08PM GMT\" , \"lt\" : \"Dec 11 5:08PM GMT\"}]";
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(jsonStr).ToObject<List<JObject>>().FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine("t = " + obj["t"]);
Console.WriteLine("l = " + obj["l"]);
```

The above print the output as

> t = GNK
>   l = 915.00

You can refer to [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/buGGDP) fiddle created for your question.

Comment: I got some error ----- A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Additional information: Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: ]. Path '', line 21, position 1.

Comment: Is your Json not is correct format. Can you please check the [created](https://dotnetfiddle.net/buGGDP) fiddle.

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Additional information: Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: ]. Path '', line 21, position 1.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: Your Json does not contain array opening bracket `[` but contains closing bracket `]`. Can you please fix your JSON string so that program works flowless.

Answer (score 1):

Parse it either split at , and then  (split on : ) add each line to dictionary using the t as the key and the other as the value.
Then you could simply access by t and also by l . 
Split the entire string by commas you have a list of item : value, then split on colon and add to dictionary. Then look up info in dictionary getvalue = Dictionary[key] ;

Answer (score 0):

You could use Regex to match the data you need:

```
string t = Regex.Match(str, "\"t\" : \"[A-Z]{3}\"").Value;
string l = Regex.Match(str, "\"l\" : \"\\d{3}.\\d{2}\"").Value;
```

Where `str` is the data string you have downloaded.

String t matches a substring that is in the format `"t" : "XXX"`, where XXX can contain any uppercase characters.

String l matches a substring that is in the format `"l" : "XXX.XX"`, where XXX.XX can contain any digit.

Answer (score 0):

1 . Add NewtonSoft.Json in your Reference in Solution Explorer. Steps(Reference [rightClick]-> Manage NuGetPackage -> Search for "Json.Net" -> Install them)

2. Add using Newtonsoft.Json;

code :

```
public class CurrentValue
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string l { get; set; }
        public string l_fix { get; set; }

        public string l_cur { get; set; }
        public string s { get; set; }
        public string lt { get; set; }
        public string lt_dts { get; set; }
        public string c { get; set; }
        public string c_fix { get; set; }
        public string cp { get; set; }
        public string cp_fix { get; set; }
        public string ccol { get; set; }
        public string pcls_fix { get; set; }

    }
```

Create a method and use following code

```
 Uri url = new Uri("http://www.google.com/finance/info?q=NSE%3A" + NameofCompany);
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                string Responsecontent = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                string CurrentContent = Responsecontent.Replace("//", "").Trim();
                var v = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CurrentValue>>(CurrentContent);
```

Now "var v" have all the data of the class "CurrentValue".

You can load a xml file containing all " NameofCompany " and Load it on FormLoad. Use a for loop to get data of all " NameofCompany "

Comment: code run but not output.  i have defined textBox1.Text = CurrentValue.t

Comment: if i want to access of var v say price of stock so how to get

Comment: string Value = v[0].l_cur.ToString().Trim().Replace("Rs.", "");  The Replace is use if you need only the Value and not the 'Rs' before it.

Answer (score 0):

i have done in follwing way

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Web;
using System.Timers;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;



namespace google_downloader
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            string s= wc.DownloadString("http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NSE:sbin");

            //index for t 
            int index7= s.IndexOf('t');
            int index8 = s.IndexOf('e');
            textBox1.Text = ("frist index is" + index7 +  "second indes is   " + index8);

            textBox1.Text = s.Substring(index7+6,(index8-index7)-10);





       }
    }
}
```